# Database load failed: Malformed database

Tags: docker, clamav

I am running a ClamAV daemon in a docker container to scan for files when uploading files.
I recently updated to clamav-0.103.2. But after some hours I get the following error.

````
Sat May 15 13:17:02 2021 -> Reading databases from /var/clamav/store

LibClamAV Error: cli_dbgets: gzread() failed

LibClamAV Error: cli_tgzload: File main.mdb not correctly loaded

LibClamAV Error: Can't load /var/clamav/store/main.cvd: Malformed database

LibClamAV Error: cli_loaddbdir(): error loading database /var/clamav/store/main.cvd
Sat May 15 13:17:19 2021 -> !reload_th: Database load failed: Malformed database

Sat May 15 13:17:21 2021 -> SelfCheck: Database status OK.

Sat May 15 13:17:21 2021 -> ^Database reload failed, keeping the previous instance```

Is this because of the newer version? As this never happened in the version 102.
Or is this something else?
````

Comment: After testing further on this I found that the issue was due to the memory limit in the server. After increasing the memory cap the database reloaded correctly and the Clam daemon ran smoothly.

Comment: A little late for you to remember maybe, but what cap did you have and what did you increase it to?